# integer solutions of $z=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers and $2012\leq z\leq 2555$.

How to solve the equation $z=\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{x}{y}$ ?

By wolfram alpha, I get $x=88,y=1,z=2024$.

Can it be solved by manual?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a Diophantine equation?

Comment: I don't know ...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2}4<z<\frac{x^2}4+x+1\\
2012<\left(\frac x2+1\right)^2,\left(\frac x2\right)^2<2555\\
2\sqrt{2012}-2<x<2\sqrt{2555}$$
If $x$ is even, then $y$ can be any factor of $x$.
If $x$ is odd, then $x/y$ must be $n+\frac34$, so $x/(y/4)$ can be any factor of $x$ which is $3\pmod4$

Answer (score 0):

**Even $x$ case:**

Clearly if $x$ is even then it is easy for $x^2$ to divide by 4.

Also $x$ must be at least 88 as $\frac{88^2}{4}+\frac{88}{1}=2024$. Note that $\frac{88^2}{4}+\frac{88}{2}=1980<2012$ so there is only one answer with $x=88$.

For $x=90,92,94,96,98,100$ there is one solution for each divisor of $x$ so that $\frac{x}{y}$ is a whole number. Note however that $\frac{100^2}{4}+\frac{100}{1}=2600$ is too big but $\frac{100^2}{4}+\frac{100}{2}=2550$ is ok.

So count up the divisors of 88-100 and eliminate out of bounds values mentioned above:

$x=88$: one solution, $y=1$

$x=90$: 12 solutions, $y=1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,30,45,90$

$x=92$: 6 solutions, $y=1,2,4,23,46,92$

$x=94$: 4 solutions, $y=1,2,47,94$

$x=96$: 12 solutions, $y=1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,96$

$x=98$: 6 solutions, $y=1,2,7,14,49,98$

$x=100$, 8 solutions, $y=2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100$

Total: 49 solutions for even $x$ case.

**Odd $x$ case:**

If $x$ is odd then $x/4$ must have a fractional part of $\frac{3}{4}$.

So for each odd number between 91 and 99 consider values of $y$ which will give this fractional part. So y must be 4 or a multiple of 4 times the multiple of a divisor of $x$.

$x=91$: two solutions, $y=4,52$

$x=93$: two solutions, $y=12,124$

$x=95$: two solutions $y=4,20$

$x=97$: no solutions as its prime

$x=99$: two solutions, $y=4,36$

$x=101$: no solutions as its prime

Total: 8 solutions of $x$ odd.

**Grand total: 57 solutions.**

Comment: $x=91,y=4,z=2093$

Comment: And $x=93,y=124$

Comment: Oops didn't search quite far enough.